# Dead mouse and keyboard: Request for brainstorming

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, mouse, logging

I'm experiencing some issues with mouse and keyboard.

I'm working as usual with the computer (Win7) but once in a while (three times a day) the computer stops responding to any command through mouse and keyboard. The computer is working without any other troubles. I'm able to connect through rdesktop, thus I usually restart the computer. I have tried to plug mouse and keyboard out and in again, uninstall all related drivers and let them get detected again, but nothing helped so far. I still have to restart the computer several times a day. I have looked into windows event logs, but there doesn't seem to be any entry about device crash.

Have anyone heard anyhing similar?

Has anybody some tips, where to look or how to fix that?

Comment: What kind of mouse/keyboard? USB cable, USB wireless? I had a wireless keyboard which acted up similar to this when the battery ran low (and no other indication anything was amiss).

Comment: these are devices connected through USB cables...

Comment: Could be a faulty USB chip on the mobo. Did you try different ports, perhaps on the opposite side of the PC (front/back)?

Comment: I have found an old discussion about very similar issue with similar hardware on [dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/18987675/19110661.aspx#19110661).
I have now additional ps/2 mouse connected, thus I don't have to connect remotely to restart the computer. Also uninstalling all usb devices do help temporarily. With sound on I can hear very often the sound of disconnection/reconnection of the device...